# Creating an index after performing groupby on DateTIme

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have the following data in the format below (see below)

[image]

I next perform recasting, groupby and averaging (see code) to reduce data dimensionality.

```
df_mod=pd.read_csv('wet_bulb_hr.csv')
#Mod Date
df_mod['wbt_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_mod['wbt_date']) 

#Mod Time
df_mod['wbt_time'] = df_mod['wbt_time'].astype('int')
df_mod['wbt_date'] = df_mod['wbt_date'] + \
                     pd.to_timedelta(df_mod['wbt_time']-1, unit='h')

df_mod['wet_bulb_temperature'] = \
df_mod['wet_bulb_temperature'].astype('float')
df = df_mod
df = df.drop(['wbt_time','_id'], axis = 1)
#df_novel = df.mean()
df = df.groupby([df.wbt_date.dt.year,df.wbt_date.dt.month]).mean()
```

After writing to an output file, I get an output that looks like this.

[image]

Investigating further, I can understand why. All my processing has resulted in a dataframe of shape 1 but what I really need is the 2 wbt_date columns to be exported as well. This does not seem to happen due to the groupby function

[image]

My question: How do I generate an index and have the groupby wbt_date columns as a new single column such that the output is:
[image]

Comment: Call ```rest_index()``` on final resultant dataframe.

Comment: @Sushanth - Do you mean reset_index()? That was one of the  first things I tried, but this was the error I got.

"ValueError: cannot insert wbt_date, already exists"

Comment: Hmm, it seems wbt_date column already exists in the dataframe try this ```reset_index(drop=True)``` which will not insert index into dataframe columns.

Comment: @Sushanth, that has remove the error, but not created the data column I wanted as I have shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten MultiIndex to Index in `YYYY-MM` by list comprehension:

```
df = df.groupby([df.wbt_date.dt.year,df.wbt_date.dt.month]).mean()
df.index = [f'{y}-{m}' for y, m in df.index]
df = df.rename_axis('date').reset_index()
```

Or use month period by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df.wbt_date.dt.to_period('m')).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: @Jezreal, of the 2 solutions, the first one using the list comprehension works. The 2nd of the 2 (which I had tried previously as well) did not work. I think its got something to do MultiIndex and 2 columns both being labelled the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
# rename exisiting index & on reset will get added as new column.

df.index.rename("wbt_year", inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['month'] = df['wbt_year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['wbt_date'].astype(str)
```

Output,

```
>>> df['month']
0    2019-0
1    2018-1
2    2017-2
```

Comment: thanks for trying. I applied it as shown above, but there is a TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`, even though you have clearly displayed an output. See the solution below; appears that list comprehension does the trick